# Possible to dynamically disable celery scheduler task?

Tags: python, celery

Is there an 'enabled' field to dynamically enable/disable a scheduled task in declaration?

```py
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
        'args': (16, 16)
        'enabled': env['PROD'] == 'True' <--- dynamically enable/disable task?
    },
}
```

Otherwise I will have to dynamically construct the `dict` like

```py
if env['PROD'] == 'True':
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE['add-every-30-seconds'] = {...}
```

The `enabled` field would look cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be hacking the `schedule` field like:

```py
class NoSchedule(BaseSchedule):
    def is_due(self, last_run_at):
        return schedstate(is_due=False, next=99999999)

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30) if env['PROD'] == 'True' else NoSchedule(),
        'args': (16, 16)
    },
}
```